# Перенос с одной даты на другую

Tags: jsp, java, sql

Нужно написать код на java (jsp) и можно (нужно) кажется запросом это всё провернуть. Есть вкладка на сайте - перенос контингента. Нужно с одной даты (раскрываются даты) перенести студентов, их номер и другие столбцы (Student1). Перенести на другую дату, т.е. заменить дату, которую выберем. Нужен запрос или код на Java, как это можно сделать. Заранее благодарен.

[image]

Comment: Изложите мысль ясно и выпукло.

Comment: на вопросы "напишите мне код" нужно отвечать "это будет стоить $N" :)
изложите более конкретным языком что вам нужно. Первое предложение "Нужно написать код нужно запросом провернуть" вообще ничего не говорит

Comment: короче мне нужно создать JSP страничку, а на ней 2 даты как на картинке раскрывающимися и кнопка перенести, перенести надо студентов с одной даты на другую...

Comment: Это не вопрос, а предложение что-то сделать за вас. Вопрос это когда есть конкретная изолированная проблема. А здесь похоже вся проблема в вас.

Comment: Кто чем может, может быть поможет? Запрос хотя бы... ПЛЗ

Comment: жесть) судя по вопросу вы не знаете ни java ни jsp ни http, да еще и толком не можете обьяснить что конкретно вам нужно. no comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно у вас используется какая-нибудь БД, в которой это все хранится.

Изменяются записи в БД с помощью оператора update.
update students set data='12/22/2012' where data '12/21/2012'

где students имя таблицы, data - имя поля в таблице.

Обычно для этого используют механизмы import java.sql
По запросу "mysql+java Пример" google выдаёт кучу всего. Естественно, если у вас не MySQL - ищите своё.

Загогулин тут несколько.
Первое. У вас очень скорее всего уже есть функции для соединения с БД, а может и для выполнения запросов - ищите.
Второе. Форматы представления даты у разных БД могут немного отличаться. Обращайте внимание!

**НИ ПРИ КАКИХ обстоятельствах НЕ работайте с живой базой данных сразу. Сначала всё на копии!!**

И только когда получится, и вы поймете, что именно сделали ,и все скажут, что "ничего не поламалось" можно что-то кудато-переность.